# Filtering results by date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
SELECT STOCK.ITEM_DATE, STOCK.AMOUNT, STOCK.OPERATIONTYPE   
       ,ITEM.ITEM_NAME 
FROM ITEM INNER JOIN STOCK ON STOCK.ITEM_ID = ITEM.ITEM_ID    
WHERE STOCK.ITEM_DATE > to_date('06/26/2013','mm/dd,yyyy')    
      AND ITEM.CATEGORY_ID = 1
```

I want to select all items before '06/26/2013' **INCLUDING** '06/26/2013', but the result is before '06/26/2013' **NOT** including '06/26/2013'.

Any ideas how to do that, i tried >= but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you setup a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: I don't think it will be eligible for me to do so... sorry.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** and include valid code to reproduce it. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: probably just a typo and not really relevant to the problem, but shouldn't it be 'mm/dd/yyyy' and not 'mm/dd,yyyy'?

Answer (score 1):

If it is:

> before '06/26/2013' INCLUDING '06/26/2013'

Then:

```
WHERE STOCK.ITEM_DATE < to_date('06/27/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: you suggest to increment the month??!!....I think increment the day makes more sense and it works fine when I added a day to the date. Thanks.